# Cannot 'git push' to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I cannot `git push` to Heroku in the normal way from my home. I've tried using two different accounts (home and work), on different apps, with different ssh keys. It's not a corrupted repo because it works from my work computer. (In fact, I normally work around this by `ssh`-ing to work and deploying from there, but the power went off there so I can't do that this weekend!)

First, this is different from dozens of other questions similar to this, primarily because I am getting **no error**.

## The Error (Non-)Message

```
$ git push heroku master
Connection closed by 50.19.85.132
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note that it hangs for exactly 60 seconds before the connection is closed and this is displayed.

```
$ git push -v heroku master
Pushing to git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git
Connection closed by 50.19.85.154
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

## What I've Tried

- `heroku keys:add` -- the command succeeds, the keys get added to my account (show on heroku.com and I get the email), but nothing changes.
- Regenerating the keys entirely. Same as above.
- Removing and re-adding the git `heroku` repo using both `git remote` and `heroku git:remote` commands. (No change.)
- Debugging the connection with `ssh -vvv`. (See below.)

## Output of Various Debugging Commands

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git (push)

$ heroku apps:info
=== myherokuapp
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git
Owner Email:   twobitalchemist@gmail.com
Region:        us
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/

$ ping -c4 50.19.85.132
PING 50.19.85.132 (50.19.85.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 50.19.85.132: icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.132: icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=49.1 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.132: icmp_seq=3 ttl=37 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.132: icmp_seq=4 ttl=37 time=49.2 ms

--- 50.19.85.132 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.997/48.832/49.245/0.498 ms

$ ping -c4 50.19.85.154
PING 50.19.85.154 (50.19.85.154) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 50.19.85.154: icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=47.8 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.154: icmp_seq=2 ttl=41 time=47.7 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.154: icmp_seq=3 ttl=41 time=49.7 ms
64 bytes from 50.19.85.154: icmp_seq=4 ttl=41 time=50.0 ms

--- 50.19.85.154 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.746/48.855/50.055/1.059 ms

$ ssh -vvv git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
[ several lines ommitted ]
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
[ hangs here ]
Connection closed by 50.19.85.132
```

## Additional Information

I'm using Arch Linux, on the same ISP I use at work (although at work we have a static IP), and I have no firewall except whatever is built into my home (Netgear) router, which is set not to block anything. I am not behind a proxy. I can deploy to GitHub just fine from here. For whatever reason, I simply can't even make the connection to Heroku. I know that my public keys are not getting rejected, and that it's simply not connecting in the first place, because the logs don't show anything and there is no activity:

```
$ heroku logs
2014-08-02T02:12:36.883623+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by twobitalchemist@gmail.com
```

---

Update: I have opened a Heroku ticket regarding this issue and am awaiting a reply from their support. I will answer here if they are able to solve the issue.

Comment: A wild guess -- decrease your MTU.

Comment: Also, what does tcpdump show when you run `ssh -vvv git@heroku.com`?

Comment: MTU here is the same as at the office (1500 bytes); tcpdump shows what I would expect for both `ssh -vvv git@heroku.com` and `git push heroku master` given what's happening -- namely, some introductory packet swapping, followed by a period of "radio silence" corresponding to the command hanging, followed by some packet swapping and a disconnect.

Comment: Is there anything on the server side that might be cause for hanging? a .bashrc with some echo or some operation waiting for input? I have seen that error when the .bashrc of the ssh shell wasn't clean. For example, a good test would be (http://serverfault.com/a/201158/783): `ssh -t git@heroku.com /bin/sh` (or even replacing the remote .bashrc: http://superuser.com/a/503785/141)

Comment: @VonC Hope not since that's out of my control on a Heroku deploy, but I feel like that would be ruled out by the fact that I can immediately turn around and `git push` from work (via ssh) with no issue. There's got to be some difference between home and work that I'm just missing or don't think is important (and in fact it's crucial).

Comment: Also, to add, there's nothing in `heroku logs` to even indicate I'm getting as far as the server. AFAIK the connection is never fully made.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist can you check the environment variables between the two client machines? There should be a difference there.

Comment: Err, sure. What environment variables in particular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it might be an issue with your security certificate.  Heroku doesn't support ECDSA key, [per their documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys).  I would create a fresh RSA SSH key that you use for heroku and only for heroku, send that new public key to them, then setup a ssh config file to serve that key when SSH reaches out to heroku.com.

This is what I have in my `~/.ssh/config` file on my laptop:

```
Host heroku.com
  IdentityFile /Users/danielrice/.ssh/identity.heroku.danielricecodes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Sorry for my own inattention to this question the past couple of days. This turned out to be correct. Not only that, I can't generate a special RSA key -- it only worked when I generated the default `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`. I am sure I could fix that with your `ssh/config` though. Thanks for helping me spot this oversight!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git@heroku.com/myherokuapp.git
```

This might not be a valid url:

```
git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git
```

Alternatively try using https format for your remote.

```
https://git@heroku.com:myherokuapp.git
```

or

```
https://git@heroku.com/myherokuapp.git
```

You may not have the correct ports open for the git protocol

Note: common URL schemes for git repositories are:

```
ssh:// - default port 22
git:// - default port 9418
http:// - default port 80
https:// - default port 443
```

I've added this because you were trying to test your ssh connectivity which is probably port 22. You possibly need to check port 9418.

Yet another option is to force git to use https:// instead of git://:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

or

```
git config --global url."https://git.somehost.com".insteadOf git://git.somehost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar issue. After verifying I had the correct RSA key format and could connect to heroku via ssh I was still getting a 'fatal: unable to connect to git.heroku.com:' error when I tried to push. Here is what worked for me:

First check to see if you have the remote set

```
git remote -v
```

If there is a remote then remove it with git remote rm [remote name]. For example in my case the remote name was 'heroku'

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Then add the remote again using the heroku command with the --ssh-git flag

```
heroku git:remote --ssh-git
```

This is based on this heroku support article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#ssh-git-transport